# Association returning name of the Model, instead of model's name attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

The code I'm running:

```
<% @organization.events.each do |event| %>
<p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= event.name %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= event.vips.name %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p>
<% end %>
```

My associations:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :vips
end

class Vip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    belongs_to :event
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :events
    has_many :vips
end
```

My events table has a vip_id column that is populated when the new event form is filled out.

The problem I'm having is that "event.vips.name" displays as "Vip" when the view is rendered.

However, the vip associated with that specific event has the name attribute "John"

Am I missing something on how to call the vip object correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `event.vips` returns a collection of `Vip` objects.

If you want to display all of the VIP's names separated by commas for instance, you could change `event.vips.name` to `event.vips.map(&:name).join(', ')`.

Or if you want to just display the first VIP's name, you could do `event.vips.first.name`.

**UPDATE**

`event.vips.pluck(:name).to_sentence` would be a more elegant solution (thanks @Simone Carletti for the suggestion).

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand the map method. Thank you, will checkmark when it's available!

Comment: You should use `pluck(:name)` instead of `map(&:name)` as it's more efficient. You can also use `pluck(:name).to_sentence` rather than using `join`.

Comment: Awesome, and if you are unfamiliar with the syntax I'm using for the `map` method, it is just a shortcut for `event.vips.map { |vip| vip.name }`. And good suggestion @Simone Carletti, I forgot about that method!