# Basic ActiveModel methods not working on objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188041/association-returning-name-of-the-model-instead-of-models-name-attribute) earlier about calling associated model attributes.

Specifically, I asked about trying to display the names of the Vip model instances associated with an event.

Initially I had

```
<% @organization.events.each do |event| %>
<p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= event.name %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= event.vips.name %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Which I changed to

```
<%= event.vips.first.name %>
```

and it worked for a little while. I eventually adjusted it to

```
<% event.vips.each do |vip| %>
  <%= vip.name %>
```

which also worked for a little while. But when I came back to the computer after taking a break, new event form submissions were no longer displaying the vip's name on the organization show page, even though the database was being updated with the vip_id foreign key.

In fact, when I tried

```
<%= event.vips.first.name %>
```

again, I got an error saying "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

I'm really not sure what changed, or what I'm doing wrong. So any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

To help clarify the problem, I get the following outputs from the console:

```
irb(main):005:0> Event.first
  Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"  ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Event id: 1, when: "2015-08-25 00:00:00", organization_id: 1, created_at: "2015-08-25 04:47:43", updated_at: "2015-08-25 04:47:43", name: "John's Event", vip_id: 1>

irb(main):006:0> Vip.first
  Vip Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "vips".* FROM "vips"  ORDER BY "vips"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Vip id: 1, name: "John", created_at: "2015-08-25 04:46:23", updated_at: "2015-08-25 04:46:23", organization_id: 1, event_id: nil>

irb(main):007:0> @organization
=> #<Organization id: 1, name: "Test Org", created_at: "2015-08-25 04:46:03", updated_at: "2015-08-25 04:46:03", user_id: 1>

irb(main):008:0> @organization.events.first
=> #<Event id: 1, when: "2015-08-25 00:00:00", organization_id: 1, created_at: "2015-08-25 04:47:43", updated_at: "2015-08-25 04:47:43", name: "John's Event", vip_id: 1>

irb(main):009:0> @organization.events.first.vips
  Vip Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "vips".* FROM "vips" WHERE "vips"."event_id" = ?  [["event_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):010:0>
```

Comment: Hi Ryan. Can you display the `Event` `vips` with a `<%= event.vips.inspect %>`? What does it return?

Comment: This means that `event.vips.first` is `nil` and hence the error. The `vips` against a particular `event` are deleted.

Comment: @Yanis Vieilly Yes, this is an example of the block going through once "John's Event #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
" when I use `<%= event.vips.inspect %>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `event` has no `vips`. Since `event.vips` is basically an empty array, calling `#first` on it returns `nil`. You then try to call `#name` on `nil`. But `#name` isn't a method of `nil`, hence the error `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: So that's part of the reason that I'm confused. If I go to console and type in `Event.first`, I'll get "=> #<Event id: 1, when: "2015-08-25 00:00:00", organization_id: 1, created_at: "2015-08-25 04:47:43", updated_at: "2015-08-25 04:47:43", name: "John's Event", **vip_id: 1** >" and when I type in `Vip.first` I get "=> #<Vip id: 1, **name: "John"**, created_at: "2015-08-25 04:46:23", updated_at: "2015-08-25 04:46:23", organization_id: 1>"

Comment: If your `Event` has many `Vip`, the `events` DB table shouldn't have a `vip_id`. I strongly recommend that you read this Rails guide which explains it in detail: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally,

1. `event.vips.first.name` will return the error you received if event.vips.first is Nil (which just means that that specific event has no vips, because .first returned Nil or nothing).
2. In some other times however  `event.vips.first` is a Vip record (which just means that that specific event has at least one Vip).

Since in my first Scenario it returned `nil`, then `nil.name` will obviously return an error. However, in my second scenario that it retuned `vip`, then `vip.name` will now work as you were expecting it to be.

You may try this if you want to disregard the error being raised: `event.vips.first.try(:name)`

Answer (score -1):

Your code will work if update the event_id of vip

```
Vip.first.update_attribute event_id, Event.first.id
```

Issue happen because we don't have an association between Event.first and Vip.first

btw, I don't think we should use event.vips.first.name because vips can be empty
We can change it a little, ex:

```
event.vips.first.try(:name)
```

or

```
event.vips.map(&:name).join(", ")
```